# Post Request not updating header info in MongoDB using Nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, post, postman

I am trying to write a very basic POST request that stores a reminder and the status of the reminder using Mongoose.
e.g. {"name":"Drink Water", "completed":false}

While testing the API on Postman the given POST request only enters the **__id** and **_v** in the database, the header info is not updated. Kindly look into the code and help me correct it.

Model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const TaskSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  completed: Boolean 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Task", TaskSchema);
```

Task Controller

```
const Task = require("../models/Task");

const getAllTasks = (req, res) => {
  res.send("Get all Available Tasks");
};
const createTask = async (req, res) => {   // code for POST req.
  const task = await Task.create(req.body);
  res.status(201).json({ task });
  
};



module.exports = {
  getAllTasks,
  createTask,
 
};
```

[image: Testing on Postman]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply `express.json()` middleware to be able to read request body.

Can you add the following line to your main file before routes?

```
app.use(express.json());
```

Comment: Yes that was the missing part. Thanks for the help.